# UpWork API not finding entity properly

Tags: upwork-api

I can get my company ID and team ID using:

`companies.Api(client).get_list()` => This returns the company ID
`companies.Api(client).get_specific('COMPANY_ID')` => This returns a list of the teams and team IDs. The company ID must be correct because the API correctly returns the teams in our company.

However, when I run:

```
time.Gds(client).get_by_team_full(company_id,team_id,params)
```

I get:

> {'errors': [{'message': 'Not Found: No entity found for parameters :
> COMPANY_ID',
> 'reason': 'other'}],  'status': 'error',  'version': '0.6'}

The documentation says to use `time.Api(client)`, but when I try that, I get:

AttributeError: module 'upwork.routers.reports.time' has no attribute 'Api'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the support team, and they pointed me to the following endpoint:
https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#companies-and-teams_list-teams-in-company

Then I used the following Upwork API method:

```
companies.Api(client).get_teams('TEAM_ID')
```

There is a character string ID that is different from the integer ID I used before. This new character string ID was the correct ID I needed to use.

Answer (score 0):

Please, [contact Support Team](https://support.upwork.com/hc/en-us/categories/115002435568), that could be related to your personal data  and can't be resolved here.